# how do i print my toString from another class

Tags: java

I am trying to print in a dialog box the book title and isbn. 
I am fairly new to java and i can't get my `toString()` to work and i need help.

```
  public class Book
    {
        private String title;
        private String author;
        private String isbn;
        private Double price;
        private Publisher publisher;

    public Book()
    {
        setTitle("");
        setAuthor("");
        setIsbn("");
        setPrice(0.0);
        setPublisher(new Publisher());
    }

    public Book(String t, String a, String i, double p, Publisher n)
    {

        setTitle(t);
        setAuthor(a);
        setIsbn(i);
        setPrice(p);
        setPublisher(n);
    }

    public void setTitle(String t)
    {
        title = t;
    }

    public String getTitle()
    {
        return title;
    }

    public void setAuthor(String a)
    {
        author = a;
    }

    public String getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public void setIsbn(String i)
    {
        isbn = i;
    }

    public String getIsbn()
    {
        return isbn;
    }

    public void setPrice(double p)
    {
        price = p;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPublisher(Publisher n)
    {
        publisher = n;
    }

    public Publisher getPublisher()
    {
        return publisher;
    }

    public double calculateTotal(int quantity)
    {
        return(price * quantity);
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return( "Title" + title + "Author" + author + "Isbn" + isbn
            + "Price" + price + "Publisher" + publisher.toString());
    }

}



import javax.swing. JOptionPane;

public class BookTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String dataArray[][] = {{"Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter","Grahame-Smith","978-0446563079","13.99", "Haper", "NY"},
                    {"Frankenstein","Shelley","978-0486282114","7.99","Pearson", "TX"},
                    {"Dracula","Stoker","978-0486411095","5.99","Double Day", "CA"},
                    {"Curse of the Wolfman"," Hageman","B00381AKHG","10.59","Harper", "NY"},
                    {"The Mummy","Rice","978-0345369949","7.99","Nelson", "GA"}}; //book info




        Book bookArray[] = new Book[dataArray.length];

        int quantityArray[] = {12, 3, 7, 23, 5};

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
        {
            bookArray[i] = new Book(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], 
                Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][3]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][4], dataArray[i][5]));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++)
        {
            bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);



        }


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Book.toString());

    }




}
```

Comment: what do you mean by `cant get my toString to work`? clarify

Comment: You are calling `toString` on `Book`, which is the class name, but you are anyways trying to call it on an array object of type `Book` meaning `bookArray[]`. Your `toString()` only applies to a single instance of `Book`. A solution will be to call `Arrays.toString(bookArray[])`

Answer (score 0):

When you qualify the method by the name of the class and not a variable that is referencing an instance of that class, you are attempting to invoke a static method named toString on the class Book.  Such a method is not defined in your Book class.

Instead, what you should be calling is  toString() on an instance of book, such as those instances that you have inside of your bookArray

For example, here is toString being invoked inside of your loop:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++)
    {
        Book b = bookArray[i];
        b.calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);
        //Using JOptionPane.showMessageDialog here only for an example, this probably isn't the OPs intent
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, b.toString();); 
    }
```

For your reference on how static works, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and [here](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/static.html).

For some extra reading on overriding toString, I refer you to a [short chapter in Effective Java, 2nd Edition.](https://books.google.com/books?id=ka2VUBqHiWkC&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=toString%20effective%20java&source=bl&ots=yZEnNnt_T_&sig=Ln95jWuYab6zefd5ZnQyYcKsDBg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zaUmVYnzIcHwsAW1t4C4Cg&ved=0CFUQ6AEwCA#v=onepage&q=toString%20effective%20java&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

When doing

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Book.toString());
```

You are trying to call `toString` statically, which is not defined in `Book`.

You need to call it from `Book` instance instead.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems so fuzzy.

The problem with toString() is in the following section of code

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++)
{
    bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Book.toString());
```

When you call Book.toString() you actually call the method from class Book. To print the content of the book you should insert that code inside for loop and use the book instances.

```
for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++)
{
    bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bookArray[i].toString());
}
```

PS: Please use an IDE and its AutoFormat utilities.

For Eclipse you can use **Control + Shift + F** and for Intellij IDEA **Control + Alt + L**